Why is the actual Padding in the OutlinedButton different from the Padding I set?
I'm trying to add padding to an OutlinedButton, but the vertical padding doesn't seem to work properly. I set the padding to 10, and when I set the child's height and width to 20, I see in the Inspector that the width of the OutlinedButton is 40, which is as expected, but the height is only 24. Why is that?Below is my code and a screenshot of the inspector.
OutlinedButton(
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        minimumSize: Size.zero,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        side: const BorderSide(
            color: mainColor,
        ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: const SizedBox(height: 20,width: 20,),
)

Inspector screenshot
In my opinion, the vertical padding should be the same as the value I set.I tried adding the same code to the OutlinedButton example and the same problem occurred.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

/// Flutter code sample for [OutlinedButton].

void main() => runApp(const OutlinedButtonExampleApp());

class OutlinedButtonExampleApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const OutlinedButtonExampleApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('OutlinedButton Sample')),
        body: const Center(
          child: OutlinedButtonExample(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class OutlinedButtonExample extends StatelessWidget {
  const OutlinedButtonExample({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        minimumSize: Size.zero,
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        side: const BorderSide(
          color: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
      onPressed: () {
        debugPrint('Received click');
      },
      child: const SizedBox(height: 20, width: 20),
    );
  }
}

Example screenshot

Could you show the code of how you wrap this button with the Row container?

@MkhytarMkhoian In my experiment, Row wrapping should have no effect, even without Row wrapping, vertical Padding does not work properly, I edited my question to add some details, there are codes practiced in the official documentation
